# Есть ли способ сделать правильный http запрос..?

Tags: сервер, http, разработка-игр, запрос, веб-сайт

Мне пришла в голову идея создать браузерную игру на JavaScript на прохождение которой дается только 1 попытка.
Можно сделать регистрацию, проверку email и т п. Но возникает одна проблема - если я хочу составить список игроков которые по-настоящему прошли игру. Возможно ли это как нибудь реализовать, и если да то как? Потому что запросы, с информацией о прохождении можно отсылать и не пройдя игру.

Comment: Тут наверное зависит что за игра, какого плана, чтобы придумать стратегию в зависимости от реализации...... Можно поступить типа "от обратного",  не просто слать запрос, клогда игра закончена, а ещё проверять на возможные читинги: например игра не может пройтись менее, чем за 10 минут или что игрок хотя бы один раз но задел припятсивие или даже так: игрок при прохождении обязательно где-то ключевые невидимые точки должен пройти или задеть. И если этого всего нет - значит читер....

Comment: Ещё отсылать на сервер время начала игры и потом время окончания. Это два разных запроса, потом сравнивать данные....что время этих запросов не менее какого-то интервала.....В общем проверка на читинг больше подходит имхо

Comment: Главное не отсылать просто флаг "gameFinished: true". Нужно отсылать много информации, которая скажет о прохождении всякого много, на основе которой можно наверняка сказать, что чел не считирил банально отослав флаг